# Coldfusion server mapping to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion server connected to MySQL database. Now I am changing the database to an existing MSSql server .. MSSql server has a similar database that of MySQL but the table names and column names are different. My question is that how can I map the new MSSql server to the ColdFusion server without changing the ColdFusion code.. Means without changing the table name and column names in ColdFusion code..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If the schemas are different (different column names and number of columns) then you probably have no choice but to refactor your CF code to reflect the new MSSQL schema. If there is a one to one relationship between the table and column names from one DB to the next you *could* use views - but it would make for a very confusing development environment. Again... each table would have to "match" for number of columns and types of data. Example

```
Old table  "users"
firstname, lastname address

New table "tblUsers" 
fname, lname, addr
```

Given the schemas above, you might have a query in your CF Code that looked like:

```
<cfquery name="getUsers" datasource="blah">
SELECT firstname, lastname, address
</cfquery>
```

So it would fail when you switched the DB. However, if you created a view like so:

```
CREATE    VIEW [dbo].[Users]
AS
SELECT  u.fname AS firstname, 
        u.lname AS lastname
        u.addr AS address
FROM    dbo.tblusers
```

Then your code would work. Again I am NOT recommending this. Your best course of action is to alter the schema to reflect your code or to refactor your code to work against the new schema. But technically it does answer your question :)

Comment: Speaking from experience, having views with the same names as table names (which is what you'd have to do to accomplish this without touching the CF code), is a *real* pain to any future developers.  It also prevents any other code from accessing the original table, which would have to be renamed.

Comment: Using sql View is a good option but what to do when in need of insert and update query.. That is more complication...

Comment: @cfde - Technically, you can run an INSERT/UPDATE on command a simple view. Though there are some restrictions.  However, I agree that in the long run, modifying your schema is the wiser course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're already using ORM, here is no handy function or mapping mechanism in CF that would allow you to do this.  There may be some manipulation at the driver level, or dipping into the java code that creates the sql strings to do text parsing there, but that's outside of my realm of expertise.

My guess, though, is that you have a lot of queries scattered throughout the application and are therefore daunted at the task of redoing all of them.  Personally, I would refactor at least the data access of this app into one or more .cfc's.  Even if all you do is wrap each query into a function call and replace the cfquery code with a function call, you're consolidating all of the database calls into one place and can change things much easier going forward.

Comment: Using ORM is a good option but my need is to do something without altering the code..